# Wordpress Post Meta Data

Tags: wordpress, metadata

I am trying to create a post meta data called youtube video link. I have able to create that also, but one problem. My meta data is not saving. When I put link in the meta data field and update the post, it doesn't save and the meta data input field is empty again. Please check my code and let me know what I am doing wrong with this.

```
<?php

/* 
 * Plugin Name: AmanHstu Video Widget
 * Author: Amanur Rahman
 * Author URI: http://www.ahsanurrahman.com
 * Plugin URI: http://www.ahsanurrahman.com
 * Description: This will show a video widget in widget section
 * Version: 1.0
 */


// Show metabox in post editing page
add_action('add_meta_boxes','amanhstu_add_metabox');

// Save Metabox Data
add_action('save_post', 'amanhstu_save_metabox');




function amanhstu_add_metabox(){
    add_meta_box('amanhstu_youtube', 'Youtube Video Link', 'youtube_video_handler', 'post');
}

  /*
     * 
     *  Meta Box handler
     */

function youtube_video_handler(){

    $value = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $youtube_link = esc_attr($value['amanhstu_youtube']['0']);
    echo '<label>Youtube Link</label> <input type="text" id="amanhstu_youtube" value="'.$youtube_link.'"  />';
}


function amanhstu_save_metabox($post_id){
    //don't save meta data if it is autosave
    if( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE){

        return;
    }

    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' )){
        return;

    }

    if( isset($_POST['amanhstu_youtube'])){

        update_post_meta($post_id, 'amanhstu_youtube', esc_url($_POST['amanhstu_youtube']));
    }



}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input needs `name` attribute to be accessible via `$_POST['amanhstu_youtube']`

```
echo '<label>Youtube Link</label> <input type="text" name="amanhstu_youtube" id="amanhstu_youtube" value="'.$youtube_link.'"  />';
```